# Print character to stdin as read by read line

Tags: c, gnu, readline

I want to print every character that is read by readline as it's read in. 
Currently I'm able to obviously print out everything after it's fully read in.
This is for a shell that is being written.

Comment: The function is called `readline` for a reason; that reason is because it allows the user to enter a 'line' of text and edit while they're doing so before the calling program, be it a shell or any other interactive program, gets to see each character. I think you're attempting to use the wrong function. You'll need something like 'curses' raw mode input — possibly without using 'curses' since that takes over the whole screen and you don't want it doing that. That said, Bash manages to interpret information as it goes; I've not checked if it uses the `readline` library, but you could look.

Comment: I need to echo what is typed back to the shell basically. I'm having trouble doing that. It doesn't have to be through readline, I just need help echoing everything. I'm using readline to actually read the command though.

Comment: OK.  You can read the manual for the readline library like I can.  Or you can wait for someone who knows the answer to come and help you out.  The more I think about it, things like tab completion in Bash suggest that Bash manages it.  So you could look at the Bash source code and see whether it uses the readline library.  If so, you can see what they use from the library.  If not, it may give you some ideas...

Answer (score 0):

readline() is a blocking function and wait for a complete line.

Just use read() in a loop. If there is no new character read() will return 0 and if a character is present it will return 1 (or n if n characters are in stdin since last call to read() and you provide a buffer big enough).
Generally the standard input has the file descriptor 0 reserved for it so your code may be like :

```
char buf[1];
int i;

while(1) {
   i = read(0, buf, 1);
   if (i>0)
    {
    // process character
    }
}
```